# Get Rotation (Tilt) Angle In Landscape View - Android Java

Tags: java, android, sensors, angle, tilt

I've scrounged the web in search of a good example or someone trying to attempt the same thing, but so far I haven't had much luck.

I am trying to get my Devices rotation angle (If you can imagine) starting at 180° (Flat).

As the user tilts the device left and right, the angle adjusts accordingly.
And as it rotates I want to simply update a TextView.

I'm just lost as to what this evolves, some people suggest a gyroscope, accelerometer, even a magnometer, or a combination.
I've gotten a few different sensors to work, but none of the examples I've followed accomplish what I want to achieve.

I don't want anything to do with 3D, just a plan rotation.

Can anybody forward me in the right director, or provide some information?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You implement OrientationEventListener this will give you the device rotation. Portrait is 0 degree.

Comment: I don't want my devices orientation (Portrait or Landscape). I want the exact angle.
Won't the OrientationEventListener wait for the Orientation to change? (Portrait or Landscape)

Comment: If you implement what I said above in onOrientationChanged(int orientation) give you the rotation angle.

Comment: Got it working, this blog post helped.
http://android-er.blogspot.ca/2010/08/orientationeventlistener-detect.html
Thank you! Just needed to know what to Google for.

Comment: @HoanNguyen thanks for your answer...How can get angle of proportion even when directly move device from Landscape to portrait or vise-versa...which is nothing but tilt angle....have any idea how can get it?

Comment: @Shubh I have no idea what do you mean by angle of proportion.