# Android orientation with sensors

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-orientation

I want to be notified when screen rotation happens. How can I do this using the sensors?

I can't use onConfigurationChanged, because I use fixed orientation on my application.

Comment: Swap the X and Y values?

Comment: No you did not understand me: I want to be notified when screen rotation happens

Comment: Then please edit your question to make it clearer what you want.

Comment: Please remember to accent the answer as correct if you used the solution provided. Thank you

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737762/get-rotation-tilt-angle-in-landscape-view-android-java/15737799#15737799

Answer (score 0):

When screen rotates (assuming OS and your app permits it), your activity is redrawn - basically, finished and recreated. You can figure out which position the phone is at the moment in by using this in your activity:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

The result of the call will be one of these: ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT and ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE

You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663665/how-can-i-get-the-current-screen-orientation), this is related to your question.

Comment: No, in a fixed orientation, this parameter does not change. I know it can be done by means of sensors, but I do not know how.

Comment: in your situation, i think yo may need to use one of the phones sensors: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html